# objective c class property variables not populated

Tags: objective-c, class, properties

I have the following simple class definition:

//mycommon.h

```
@interface CurrentPath : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* PathString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* PathArr;
- (void) addAddressToPath:(NSString*) address;
@end
```

//mycommon.m

```
@implementation CurrentPath : NSObject

@synthesize PathString;
@synthesize PathArr;

- (void) addAddressToPath:(NSString*) address{
    NSLog(@"addAddressToPath...");

    // Add to string
    self.PathString = [self.PathString stringByAppendingString:address];

    // Add to Arr
    [self.PathArr addObject:address];
}

@end
```

In another class I do `#import<mycommon.h>` and declare the variable like this:

```
@interface myDetailViewController : 
{
        CurrentPath* currentPath;
}
- (void) mymethod;
    @end
```

and in

```
@implementation myDetailViewController

- void mymethod{
self->currentPath = [[CurrentPath alloc] init];
NSString* stateSelected = @"simple";
    [self->currentPath addAddressToPath:stateSelected];
}
@end
```

Problem is that the PathString and PathArr properties of self->currentPath are empty after this method call which I think should have "simple" in them. Please help!

Comment: Where you are allocating memory to PathArr?

Comment: hmm. I think @synthesize should do so. Lets say it doesn't still the instance function addAddressToPath should populate PathString. But when I try to print it after method call it prints null. shouldn't it be "simple".

Comment: no @synthesize will not do that, you need to first check the memory management rules and definitions generated by synthesize.

Comment: I did `self.pathArr = [self.pathArr initWithObjects:@"", nil];` in custom constructor but still its not adding "simple" on `[self.currentPath addAddressToPath:@"simple"];`. Can you give me any idea how can i allocate memory for this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that your `NSString` and `NSMutableArray` properties are initialized when your `CurrentPath` object is created. Otherwise, the call to `stringByAppendingString` will result in `nil` because it is sent to a `nil` object.

One feasible way would perhaps be

```
self.currentPath = [NSString string];
// or
self.currentPath = @"";
[self.currentPath addAddressToPath:@"simple"];
```

More elegant and robust would be to check for nil property in the `addAddressToPath` method.

```
if (!self.pathString) self.pathString = [NSString string]; 
if (!self.pathArr) self.pathArr = [NSMutableArray array];
```

*Notice that am following the objective-c convention and use property names that start with lower case letters.*

Comment: true. what about pathArr? I do an `[self.pathArr addObject:address];` in **addAddressToPath** function but the Array size doesn't change. "simple" is not added to Arr.

Comment: Exactly the same argument. Will edit answer for the benefit of others.